# Spring ws configuration wsdl generation strategy?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, wsdl, spring-ws

I am using spring-ws. I think there are two ways of generating WSDL.

`dynamic wsdl` and `static wsdl` approaches.

Could you please suggest me which is better approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to the XSDs, those nice folks who created Spring-WS recommend contract-first. Their manual explains why this is the case:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/why-contract-first.html

... which is good enough for me.

Whether to dynamically generate the WSDL is not so much of an issue. However, in the past I have needed to generate WSDL which complies with strict corporate standards. If that is something you need to do then you should stick with static. Additionally, I have needed to tweak WSDL to ensure that the service definition plays nicely with .NET clients. Again, the only way to do that is if you have written the WSDL yourself.

Of course, if you're still learning your way around WSDL, you may find it easier to generate it initially. If you need to go static later, then can then take a copy of the generated WSDL as your starting point.

Comment: Steve, does generating wsdl dynamically time consuming? Thanks!

Comment: Not noticeably so. I believe that it's generated during startup of your application, so it's not having to re-calculate it every time someone makes a request to the WSDL.

Comment: Steve, Thanks for your reply. so if i use dynamic wsdl then there will not be any issues right? because if i go for static wsdl then everytime i need to change my static wsdl if there are any changes.am i correct? in case of dynamic wsdl i need not worry since it is generated runtime.

Comment: Exactly. The dynamic WSDL generation does a good job. A static WSDL is only really needed if you need to do something a little bit different. Until you're confident with your WSDL skills, allowing Spring-WS to do the generation for you is a good way to go. When you become confident, then you'll find that updating the WSDL for new operations is actually not that bad. :)

Comment: Spring documentation recommends using dyanmic wsdl generation only during development, and downloading and using the static wsdl after that.  See here for reasons: (section 5.3.1.1) http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html       "It is therefore recommended to only use <dynamic-wsdl> during the development stages of your project. Then, we recommend to use your browser to download the generated WSDL, store it in the project, and expose it with <static-wsdl>. This is the only way to be really sure that the WSDL does not change over time."